# How to provide external power to portable hard disk - WD Elements?

Tags: hard-drive, usb

The package comes only with a USB cable and the hard disk powers from usb. However, i need a setup that can power this hard disk externally. How can I achieve that?

Comment: For what reason? What is your HDD capacity.

Comment: 1 TB Capacity - Need to connect this one to a screen which can't provide power to usb hard drives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest (and cheapest) solution would be to use a powered USB hub.

Plug the hub into the screen and then the drive into the hub.

Just google "powered USB Hub".

If your screen can't understand USB hubs (unusual, but possible), then I'd look at the answers to this question over on Electronics Overflow:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123585/can-the-power-source-for-a-usb-device-be-different-from-the-data-source

Comment: True. The hub doesn't work with screen. Had tried that already. And the solution discussed in the link you gave is not something I could understand. Please do let me know if there was a simple / ready-made solution in your knowledge.

Comment: Never mind. It just occured to me to buy a cable which bifurcates the power and put that power cable (usb) in the usb hub. Right? That should work?